# Present perfect: when do we need to change the gender and number of the past participle in accordance with the subject?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-participle

Example: «*Siamo entrati senza la chiave*».

I thought the passato prossimo form for *entrare* was *entrato* and that the conjugation should have affected only *essere* or *avere*.
But apparently that is not the case. So what is the general rule here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With intransitive verbs the past participle in the *passato prossimo* always agrees with the subject in its gender and number: *siamo entrati*, *sono andata* (if the speaker is a female) and so on.

For transitive verbs, the situation is trickier. In “normal”, subject-verb-object, sentences, the past participle is used in the singular masculine (*Abbiamo mangiato la bistecca*), independently on the subject and the object.

However, when the object is a pronoun and precedes the verb, the participle agrees *with the object*: *l'ho mangiata* (where *l(a)* refers to a *bistecca*), *ci hanno battuti* and so on.

Comment: About the last point: Agreement is only obligatory with third-person pronouns.